# Example of such groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does there exist $G$ such that  for a subgroup $H$ of $G$ , $gHg^{-1}$ is proper in $H$ for some $g\in G$ ?

It is clear that $H,G$ must be infinite. I look for examples in matrice groups and not found yet.

Comment: Yes. There should be several questions about this with answers.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Can you give link please ?

Comment: This was discussed for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312131/does-ghg-1-subseteq-h-imply-ghg-1-h). I've also seen more natural exaples ($G=S(\mathbb{Z})$, $H$ subgroup fixing all negative elements, and $g=(k \mapsto k+1)$, if I remember correctly) but cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991705/if-ghg-1-subset-h-must-we-have-g-1hg-subset-h?lq=1) it is.

Comment: An older question, with more answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup

Answer (score 0):

Take $G$ the group of affine transformations of $\mathbb{Q}$ , $G= \{(a,b) \ | \ a \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with $ (a,b)$ acting as $t \mapsto a t + b$. Take $g = (2,0)$ and $H = \{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}$. We have $g H g^{-1} = \{1\} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$.

As groups of matrices let $G = $ matrices of form $
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right)$ with $a \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$, $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $H $ matrices of form $
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & n\\
0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right)$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

The idea was to use a semidirect product $L \rtimes T$ where $T$ is a group of automorphisms of $L$ that contains a transform taking a subgroup $H$ of $L$ to a proper subgroup of $H$.